# What should be the complexity

Tags: time-complexity

What should be the complexity of the function in the Worst case?

Input:

```
FreeText = "My Name is shobhit and I live in istabul";
SearchText = "is";
```

Function is:

```
ReplaceText(FreeText , SearchText);
```

Output:

```
My Name  shobhit and I live in tabul
```

Comment: How is `I` being replaced if the search text is `is`?

Comment: its by mistake good catch

Comment: @ShobhitWalia: you *can* edit your question, I guess. Your call to `ReplaceText` does not make sense. It needs at least three arguments: string (buffer) to be modified, search text, replacement text. And it should probably return a pointer to the buffer.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis m not using language specific syntax here. definitely this function should return string. My concerned is not about the language syntax, I just want what should be the complexity in the Worst Case.

Comment: You tagged this as C. Expect people to see this as a question about C. Anyway, even in different languages, you will have to have these three arguments if you want to *replace* text: string, search text, replacement text. If you don't ask about specifics, your question risks being closed for being too broad, or for being unclear about what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 3):

The worst case complexity is bounded by the input string lenght. So in your case let's suppose you have a sentence of n words the complexity is o(n),in the worst case, to find the word is. If you have a sentence composed only of "is" your complexity is o(n^2) to find and replace all the "is".

Comment: If you need code, then you should either try to find some, or write it yourself. This is not a code writing service. And if you update your question to show what you have already tried, people can help you with specific problems. Now you just risk a number of downvotes and a closure.